# Change p text clicking on checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

i'm basically trying to change the text on "p" when clicking, but so far I haven't been successful using javascript. Can you guys help me?

```
<div class="switch">
<h2>Switch Text</h2>
<div class="switch-button">
    <input class="switch-button-checkbox" type="checkbox"></input>
    <label class="switch-button-label" for="">
      <span class="switch-button-label-span">Click Here!</span></label>
  </div>
    <p>Change this. <br>Change this. </p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main way to interact/change a webpage is to use javascript.
In this example, the `onclick` attribute of the button is set to call a function that turns sets the text of all elements with the given classname to an input  text, in this case "This has been changed".

At your request, I've updated it to allow the text to turn back to it's initial value. This is by adding a parameter that the element will be set to **if it is currently the value it should be changed to on the first click**

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="switch">
      <h2>Switch Text</h2>
      <div class="switch-button">
          <input class="switch-button-checkbox" type="checkbox" onclick="changeText('textToChange','This has been changed','<p class=\'textToChange\'>Change this. <br>Change this. </p>')">
          <label class="switch-button-label" for="">
            <span class="switch-button-label-span" onclick="changeText('textToChange','This has been changed','<p class=\'textToChange\'>Change this. <br>Change this. </p>')">Click Here!           </span>
          </label>
      </div>
      <p class="textToChange">Change this. <br>Change this. </p>
    </div>
    <script>
    function changeText(classToChange,textToChangeTo,initalText){
      var ElementsToChange = document.getElementsByClassName(classToChange);
      Array.from(ElementsToChange).forEach( (element) =>{
        if(element.innerHTML!= textToChangeTo){
          element.innerHTML=textToChangeTo;
          element.style.color="blue";
          element.style.fontSize="150%";
          document.getElementsByClassName("switch-button-checkbox")[0].checked=true;
        }
        else{
          element.innerHTML=initalText;
          element.style.color="black";
          element.style.fontSize="100%";
          
          document.getElementsByClassName("switch-button-checkbox")[0].checked=false;
        }
      });
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I looked for, thanks :). But what if I want to go back to the original text unchecking the checkbox? How can i do?

Comment: @KevenCrisostomo , I've added that into my edit <3

Comment: when you click on the text "Click Here!", the state of the box doesn't change

Comment: @Trolzen I wasn't aware that was a requirement. Regardless, I have edited

Comment: @StarshipladDev I think if to provide a solution, then it should be bug-free. So not to multiply bad practices and incomplete examples out there in the wild.

Comment: @Trolzen we all know the pain of adamant client-requests that seem to be purposefully non-user friendly/ buggy however :p

Answer (score 2):

Listen for the `change` event.

Also, for your label to work, you need to assign an `id` to the input and use that same `id` for the `for` attribute in your label.

```js
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(){
  document.querySelector('p').textContent = "changed";
})
```

```html
<div class="switch">
<h2>Switch Text</h2>
<div class="switch-button">
    <input class="switch-button-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <label class="switch-button-label" for="checkbox">
      <span class="switch-button-label-span">Click Here!</span></label>
  </div>
    <p>Change this. <br>Change this. </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) event

for more information check this article https://errorsea.com/how-to-change-text-onclick-event-javascript/

```js
function change_text(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "This is my text changed.";
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
<h2>Switch Text</h2>
<div class="switch-button">
    <input class="switch-button-checkbox" onclick="change_text()" type="checkbox"></input>
    <label class="switch-button-label" for="">
      <span class="switch-button-label-span" onclick="change_text()"  >Click Here!</span></label>
  </div>
    <p id="demo">Change this. <br>Change this. </p>
```

Comment: this doesn't work when one clocks on the text "Click Here!", and not on the box

Comment: fixed so it changes if you check the box, or click on the text "Click Here!".
This can be achieved by adding the onclick="change_text()"  as an attribute of the html tag

Comment: clicking on text changes the contents of <p>, but the box remains clear